# Drawable scale factor for "drawable-large-mdpi"

Tags: android, drawable

we know that the drawable scale factor for hdpi, xhdpi and ldpi.
ie., hdpi=1.5*mdpi, xhdpi=2*mdpi and ldpi=.75*mdpi.

But what I need is the scale factor for "drawable-large-mdpi" & "drawable-xlarge-mdpi".
Because I need to design UI for 7" and 10" tablet.
Please provide the scale factor for drawable-large-mdpi & drawable-xlarge-mdpi.

Answer (score 0):

The scale factors for `drawable-large-mdpi` and `drawable-xlarge-mdpi` have the same scale factor as `mdpi`. The `large` and `xlarge` identifiers specify the screen size.

According to [Android - Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range):

> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
>   large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
>   normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
>   small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

You should only use the density qualifiers for your drawables, by providing them for each density. The screen size qualifiers should be used to specify for what screen sizes your layout is suitable.

For example `res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png` provides an icon for a 'medium' density and `res/layout-large/my_layout.xml` provides a layout for a 'large' screen.

Comment: But for 7" and 10" drawables, am still facing problem in sizes. Do i need to use trial and error method for size of drawables for tablets or any specific relation is there? pls clarify.

Comment: There is not such thing as a 7" or 10" drawable. Drawables have a certain density specified in `dpi`. Screens have certain sizes specified in `dp` (or in inch if you want). So what you need to do is provide the drawables for the supported densities and layouts for the supported screen sizes. Android will then grab the correct drawables and layouts depending on the device specifications. Figure 1 on the [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) I provided, shows a coarse mapping of regular relations between density and screen size.

Comment: Now i have attached 2 images in my question, please check that clarify the same.

Comment: You want you layout to be sized to full screen on a 10" screen, even though it get ridiculously large?! As I said: You need to provide different **layouts** for each supported screen size... Ie to scale the drawable to full screen or to put it centered at a common size. The choice is yours!

Comment: if i need to place different layouts for 10" tab, then do i need to place the xml in layout-xlarge-mdpi ?

Comment: Please read [the page I provided](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), it will provide clarity and provides the answers of your questions. In this case you need to put the `layour.xml` in `res/layout-xlarge` (without the *mdpi* part)

Answer (score 0):

The large and xlarge factors don't have a scale factor. You create a new design for them.
You should see it like this:

- there are 4 different device sizes atm: small, normal, large, xlarge.
- Every device size has multiple scale factors atm these are: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi

These "Buckets" are changing when screens and device sizes change. I think i read something about the factor xxhdpi yesterday.

You can read more about this subject over here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html